# reactjs youtube video autoplay can be possible without muted?

Tags: jquery, html, reactjs

[react-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player)

I am using this module on my react app, youtube video play is played automatically, but muted should be true because of browser policy. So I tried to customize the mute setting with onPlay() callback function from react-player. but instead of it, youtube video is stopped to play, and I can see following notification on browser console.

Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user didn't interact with the document before.

Any idea? please help me. I want to make this video player to be played automatically without muted.

Comment: On page focus, unmute the video player?

Comment: unmute video autoplay

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, you may want to change Chrome autoplay policy behavior locally to test your website for different levels of user engagement.

You can disable the autoplay policy entirely by using a command line flag: `chrome.exe --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required`. This allows you to test your website as if user were strongly engaged with your site and playback autoplay would always be allowed.

You can also decide to make sure autoplay is never allowed by disabling MEI and whether sites with the highest overall MEI get autoplay by default for new users. Do this with flags: `chrome.exe --disable-features=PreloadMediaEngagementData, MediaEngagementBypassAutoplayPolicies`.

For more information you can check this: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/